# expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char (*)[1000]'

Tags: c, pointers

I've been trying to figure out to get away with an error with what the title say. I'm aware that I set up a 2D array and then tried to pass it to a function which asked for a pointer and it gave me an error about the argument.

Then I tried to make the function accept a double pointer instead but a part of my code received another error about how incompatible it is to compare values of double pointer and a single pointer.

i also have global variables and typedef struct

```
int main() {
    char text[5][1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < parano; i++) {
        do {
            scanf("%[^\n]s", text[i]);
        }while((getchar()) != '\n');
        }

    doc = initialize_document(text);
}

document initialize_document(char *text) {

//code
}
```

I just need to find a way to make it possible for a 2D array to be passed as a pointer. I'm just starting out coding so I'm not sure if that's possible so I'm asking for help.

Comment: Note that text is a pointer to a pointer the error can be expected

Answer (score 0):

Change line 13 to:

```c
document initialize_document(const char text[5][1000]) {
  /* your code */
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use global variables.

Comment: That `const` will be a problem.